# asp.net css navigation bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to create a css navigation bar for asp.net links.

```
<div> 
    @{
        foreach (LangViewModel langViewModel in Model.Langs)
        {
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink(langViewModel.Name, "Lang", "Home", new { 
         langID = langViewModel.Id }, new { })
            </p>
        }
 </div>
```

this code generates 3 links which direct me to other pages of my website namely

```
Numbers
Alpha
Alphanumeric
```

now i want have these 3 links generated by asp.net in navigation bar.
[i was using w3schools as reference.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black)
for this to work we need to use `<ul> and <li>`tags in following way with some css.

```
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

but my links are generated in ASP.NET code above so  what should i write in so that could get a navigation bar.

```
<li><a class="active" href="WHAT SHOULD DO HERE">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Change your div and p tag to use `ul` and `li`. What is the problem you are having ?

Comment: what should  i do in href tag i cannot keep a link as my links are dynamic

Comment: @raju dynamic means are you getting them from database.

Answer (score 1):

> Model

```
public class Langs
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Langs> lidemo = new List<Langs>();
        lidemo.Add(new Langs { ID = 1, Name = "Home" });
        lidemo.Add(new Langs { ID = 2, Name = "About Us" });
        lidemo.Add(new Langs { ID = 3, Name = "Contact" });
        lidemo.Add(new Langs { ID = 4, Name = "Page 1" });
        lidemo.Add(new Langs { ID = 5, Name = "Page 2" });
        return View(lidemo);
    }
}
```

> View

[image: View]

> Output

[image]

> Link For Markup
>     [Link For Mark of Navigation Bars](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h)